# How to implement 'Did you mean?' - spell checker functionality like google in Sitecore using Lucene/Solr?

Tags: solr, content-search, lucene

I have a requirement to implement google-like 'Did you mean?' functionalities. If user make a mistake in typing then I've to show 'Did you mean `[correct search term]`'.

What is the best way in sitecore to implement this?

Comment: Have you seen the blogpost by Ehab ElGindy: http://www.ehabelgindy.com/sitecore-7-solr-spellcheck/ ? There is also this post from Alexander Smagin: http://alexander-smagin.blogspot.dk/2014/05/sitecore-solr-spell-check.html?m=1.

Comment: What search engine are you using? Google Search? Solr? Lucene? any other?

Comment: @Diego I am using Lucene but I want to know the implementation approach using solr as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this using spellcheck dictionary.

- Create a composite tokenized index field using custom n-gram analyzer with help of ShingleFilter.
- Create a custom spellcheck dictionary.
- Get suggested words from the dictionary.

For achieving this in Sitecore using Lucene, download the available source code for **"Sitecore Cookbook for Developers"** from -

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Sitecore-Cookbook-For-Developers/tree/master/Chapter%209/7.%20Correcting%20a%20search%20with%20did%20you%20mean

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the SpellChecker package. There are versions of this module for both Lucene and Solr, as well as .NET ports for Lucene.Net (which is what Sitecore uses). Make sure you get the version of the plugin appropriate for the version of Lucene / Solr you are using.

Remember that when dealing with Lucene or Solr, there exists a large community of developers across both Java and Windows platforms. Most search related questions are not particular to Sitecore.

For example, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348093/did-you-mean-feature-in-lucene-net